# R: assigning values to a new matrix based on value and coordinate in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a symmetrical matrix `m1` and I would like to create a second matrix `m2` depending on the value and the location in `m1`.

For example (apologies for the poor pseudocode):

```
> m1
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    0    5    6    7
[3,]    2    5    0    8    1
[4,]    3    6    8    0    9
[5,]    4    7    1    9    0
```

If the value is in position (x1-3 and y4-5) or (x4-5 and y1-3), and if the value itself is >2, then "A",
else if it's in those positions but <3 then "B",
else if it's (x1-3 and y1-3) or (x4-5 and y4-5) and >2 then "C",
else "D".
And if possible to ignore the diagonal.

So that:

```
> m2
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    NA   D    D    A    A
[2,]    D    NA   C    A    A
[3,]    D    C    NA   A    B
[4,]    A    A    A    NA   C
[5,]    A    A    B    C    NA
```

I can use `m2 <- ifelse(m1 >2 , "A", "B")` for all values regardless of position, but I'm stumped for how to do it just for certain positions. I've also tried things like `m1[1:3,4:5]` as nested if statements but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
idxc <- col(m1)
idxr <- row(m1)
msk <- idxr %in% 1:3 & idxc %in% 1:3 | idxr %in% 4:5 & idxc %in% 4:5
m1[msk] <- ifelse(m1>2,"C","D")[msk]
m1[!msk] <- ifelse(m1>2,"A","B")[!msk]
m2 <- `diag<-`(m1,NA)
```

which gives

```
> m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] NA   "D"  "D"  "A"  "A" 
[2,] "D"  NA   "C"  "A"  "A" 
[3,] "D"  "C"  NA   "A"  "B" 
[4,] "A"  "A"  "A"  NA   "C" 
[5,] "A"  "A"  "B"  "C"  NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(m1)
structure(c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 
8L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 0L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 0L), .Dim = c(5L, 
5L))
```

Comment: This works great - thank you! My only request would be to not overwrite m1 but retain the original values too, if possible.

Comment: @P_Jefferies You can first create `m2` by `m2 <- m1` at the beginning of my code, and then replace all `m1` by `m2`. That will give you both original  `m1` and resulting `m2`.